# python compile fail on centos6.9 (32bit)

Tags: python, gcc, makefile

Hi I follow the step online which is:

```
 # wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz

 # tar xzf Python-2.7.13.tgz

 # cd Python-2.7.13

 # ./configure

 # make

 # make altinstall
```

and it gave me the following compile error:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/symtablemodule.c -o Modules/symtablemodule.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/xxsubtype.c -o Modules/xxsubtype.o
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE \
          -DSVNVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C svnversion .`\"" \
          -DHGVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C hg id -i .`\"" \
          -DHGTAG="\"`LC_ALL=C hg id -t .`\"" \
          -DHGBRANCH="\"`LC_ALL=C hg id -b .`\"" \
          -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c: In function 'Py_GetBuildInfo':
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:45: error: expected ')' before 'default'
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:46: error: expected ')' before 'default'
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:46: error: expected ')' before 'default'
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:47: error: expected ')' before 'default'
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:47: error: expected ')' before 'default'
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c: In function '_Py_hgversion':
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:72: error: expected ';' before 'default'
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c: In function '_Py_hgidentifier':
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:79: error: expected ';' before 'default'
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:83: error: expected ';' before 'default'
make: *** [Modules/getbuildinfo.o] Error 1
```

I try searching online but cant find any solution... 
any help is appreciated

Thanks!

After looking at the comments below I changed the function to (marked with //<-added by me):

```
const char *
Py_GetBuildInfo(void)
{
//    static char buildinfo[50 + sizeof(HGVERSION) +
//                          ((sizeof(HGTAG) > sizeof(HGBRANCH)) ?
//                           sizeof(HGTAG) : sizeof(HGBRANCH))];
    static char buildinfo[500];  //<-added by me

    const char *revision = _Py_hgversion();
    const char *sep = *revision ? ":" : "";
    const char *hgid = _Py_hgidentifier();
    if (!(*hgid))
        hgid = "default";
    PyOS_snprintf(buildinfo, sizeof(buildinfo),
                  "%s%s%s, %.20s, %.9s", hgid, sep, revision,
                  DATE, TIME);
    return buildinfo;
}

const char *
_Py_svnversion(void)
{
    /* the following string can be modified by subwcrev.exe */
    static const char svnversion[] = SVNVERSION;
    if (svnversion[0] != '$')
        return svnversion; /* it was interpolated, or passed on command line */
    return "Unversioned directory";
}

const char *
_Py_hgversion(void)
{
    //return HGVERSION;
    return "Unversioned version";  //<-added by me

}

const char *
_Py_hgidentifier(void)
{
//    const char *hgtag, *hgid;        
//    hgtag = HGTAG;
//    if ((*hgtag) && strcmp(hgtag, "tip") != 0)
//        hgid = hgtag;
//    else
//        hgid = HGBRANCH;
//    return hgid;
   return "Unversioned id"; //<-added by me

}
```

my question is if its save to do that ? because the code seems to compile and I can install it without a problem.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue12346

Comment: [Similar issue on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/564118/error-compiling-python-2-7-3-on-centos5)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following -
1) upgrade all mercurial packages to the latest version, and then try to build python 2.7, if that still doesn't compile, then
2) remove mercurial packages first, then build python 2.7, and re-install mercurial afterwards.